# Is there a performance advantage in using an object literal over a self instantiated constructor?

Tags: javascript, performance, object

### Question

Is there a performance advantage in using an object literal over a self instantiated constructor?

### Examples

Object literal:

```
var foo = { 
    //... 
};
```

Self instantiated constructor:

```
var foo = new function () {
    //...
};
```

Comment: see http://jsperf.com/object-notation-vs-constructor

Comment: Modified perf (see rev. 5) did not expect `Object.create` to be so slow!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes (the object literal *will* be faster), but they are subtly different in implementation<sup>1</sup> and represent different goals. The constructor form "has to do a bunch more stuff" while the literal form can also be more highly optimized - it is a definition (of an as-of-yet-fixed set of properties), and not a sequence of statements.

Even though a [*micro-benchmark*](http://jsperf.com/object-notation-vs-constructor) (which is interesting, thanks Arun!) might show one being "much slower", it Just Doesn't Matter in a real program<sup>2</sup> as the amount of relative time spent in either construct approaches nothing.

---

<sup>1</sup> When a constructor is used [a prototype *must* be introduced](http://es5.github.io/#x4.2.1). This is not the case with an object literal due to it's *fixed* chain behavior.

> Every object created by a constructor has an implicit reference (called the object’s prototype) to the value of its constructor’s “prototype” property.

Other overhead work includes creating a new execution context, copying over additional properties, and even checking the return value. (In the posted case it also has to create a *new* one-off function object before it can even use is as a constructor which itself adds some [additional overhead](http://jsperf.com/object-notation-vs-constructor/2)).

<sup>2</sup> I'm sure there are counter-examples. But for such cases, I can only hope that the problem has been thoroughly benchmarked with all other bottlenecks identified and removed.